# Set a default value for ad-grid width. Before it does its math and resize

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When ag-grid is loaded after the initial page load it first renders with a `0px` (or small number of px) width then it does its math and sets its width to the width of parent. It does so by adding inline styles to 2 of its html elements.

Is there a way to deactivate this behaviour or at least to set the default value to be something else then `0px` (i.e.: like `100%`)?

If I use the `layoutInterval: -1` option the grid still starts with `0px` (or small number of px) and stays like that.

So I currently have to use `width: 100% !important` (on `.ag-bl-center`) on these elements to prevent the grid from flickering when loading. I would prefer a clean solution if possible but didn't find anything in the docs.

```
<ag-grid-angular
 style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;"
 [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
 [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
 [rowData]="rows"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Mention `why` would you like to do that. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1417185)

Comment: To prevent the grid from flickering when loading

Comment: Does the [main demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php) also have this problem? I don't see anything wrong with it, as such. If that demo doesn't do it, but your page does, there's something on your page that's causing it. And you haven't shared enough relevant code for us to help you.

Comment: @thirtydot Maybe you're right ... but since my grid is loaded in Angular in a modal following user interaction and NOT on initial page load, the grid might not be able to its math correctly. The `doLayout()` should resizes to fit the div the grid lives in. This is done a) on initialisation b) window resize and c) every 500ms. But I'll keep checking maybe it's just a bad CSS.

Comment: If you need more help, create a demo that reproduces your problem. You can start from any example in [the documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php), such as [this one](https://plnkr.co/edit/BdfaOHKhzKQpHY5WFojL?p=preview).